# Why does the group $\mathbb{Z}^d \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^k$ have exponential growth?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I apologize if this is posted on the wrong forum, I was reading [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139158/growth-rate-of-mathbbz2-rtimes-sigma-mathbbz) question on MathOverflow which asks about "growth rate of $\mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_{\sigma} \mathbb{Z}$". The last comment of the answer mentions the group $G=\mathbb{Z}^d \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^k$ with $k>1$ as an example of a polycyclic-by-finite group with exponential growth rate. Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Edit: Gromov's theorem states that every group of polynomial growth is virtually nilpotent. Should I try to show that the above group is not virtually nilpotent?

Comment: First and foremost: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_%28group_theory%29

Comment: So I see $Z^d$ has polynomial growth rate of order $d$, but what does the semidirect product do to the growth rate?

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about *the group* ${\mathbb Z}^d \rtimes {\mathbb Z}^k$.To define a semidirect product, you need to specify a homomorphism $\sigma:{\mathbb Z}^k \to {\rm Aut}({\mathbb Z}^d)$. Whether or not the growth is exponential depends on $\sigma$. In fact, by a deep result of Gromov, the growth is polynomial if and only if the group is virtually nilpotent. otherwise it will be exponential. (There do exist examples of groups with intermediate growth, but not of this type.)

Comment: @DerekHolt In the example that you gave, what would the map be? Sorry I couldn't comment on that comment because I didn't have enough point on MathOverflow.